# Accessing React App externally, when running 'npm start'

Tags: reactjs, npm, create-react-app, npm-scripts

I'm using `create-react app`. In order to view the project in the browser locally:

1. In the command line, in the application directory I type the command `npm start`
2. In the browser I type `http://localhost:3000/` for the URL on the same computer (Or other port I specify).

I'd like to be able to access the project from browsers on other computers as well. This is for the purpose of QA. How can I set it? Is there a way to set it in the `package.json` file, and without `npm eject`?

Comment: Are the other machines on the same network? You can just access it using your machine IP?

Comment: @SatejS, the other computer are on the same network. I tried accessing them with my API, it works for a tomcat server I run on Eclipse, but not for my React project. The URL I tried is: `${ip}:${port}.

Answer (score 0):

You can establish Public Connection using `ngrok`. When you run ngrok you instantly get a public address to your local development machine.
You share generated public Ngrok link (viz. http://92832de0.ngrok.io) with other users. They connect to Ngrok and this connection between their pc and Ngrok is referred to as Public Connection